# Windows 11 Snap Layouts: force all 6 layout options (irrespective of display resolution)?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, snap, windows-snap-assist

I noticed that on Windows 11, upon pressing `Win`+`z`, on my smaller screen I have ...

[image: 4 snap layout options]

...while on my bigger one I have two more options:

[image: 6 snap layout options]

(And if you upvote this question,then next time I'll be able to post actual images instead of just links :-)

Can you think of a trick to force Windows 11 to ***always*** offer all 6 layout options, even on smaller screens? Maybe through a registry hack?

Below are listed all `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`-registry entries including the keywords *flyout* or *snap* — just in case this helps:

```
"EnableFlyout"=dword:00000001

"FlyoutUrl"="https://windows.msn.com:3/shell"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ms-meetnowflyout]

@="Meet Now Flyout"

"Name"="ms-meetnowflyout"

"ms-meetnowflyout"="AppXpzkxgsbx9mzsg8kedsrg3eqxykxrtcx"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ms-meetnowflyout]

@="URL:ms-meetnowflyout"

"SettingsExtensionAppshot"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"Sizing"="1"

"ToDefaultButton"="1"

"ishotResolution"=dword:0000008

"bUseFixedshotResolution"=dword:00000000

"UIshot"=hex(7):31,00,30,00,33,00,31,00,00,00

" ITC"=dword:00000000

" ITC"=hex:0,0,0a,07,0,0a,02,02,02,02

"ToGrid"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Notifications\BackgroundCapability\S-1-15-2-1850972-32280828-308873538-20108251-97529272-3239085-22050315\Global..AppX58dwf1xwjzeer05zcpfeag883wvc9y0.wwa]

"AppUserModelId"="MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_cw5n1h2txyewy!Global."

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Notifications\BackgroundCapability\S-1-15-2-1850972-32280828-308873538-20108251-97529272-3239085-22050315\Global..AppXtq1qr7x809h0sw08qzdq0nerjx.mca]

"AppUserModelId"="MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_cw5n1h2txyewy!Global."

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Notifications\BackgroundCapability\S-1-15-2-28321221-31835570-1718213290-75155359-3515923-231220959-33792851\Global..AppXjzn3exz1kne7z53qwmqvrdmfjvhsx.mca]

"AppUserModelId"="MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy!Global."

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Notifications\BackgroundCapability\S-1-15-2-28321221-31835570-1718213290-75155359-3515923-231220959-33792851\Global..AppXy7qkeqtnpyae122cbeqn07bmsyce.wwa]

"AppUserModelId"="MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy!Global."

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\DefaultAccount\Cloud\{88eeedb-a29-88-9078-f9fab0ca030}$windows.data.settings.multitasking.windows]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\DefaultAccount\Cloud\{88eeedb-a29-88-9078-f9fab0ca030}$windows.data.settings.multitasking.windows\windows.data.settings.multitasking.windows]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\DefaultAccount\Current\{88eeedb-a29-88-9078-f9fab0ca030}$windows.data.settings.multitasking.windows]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\DefaultAccount\Current\{88eeedb-a29-88-9078-f9fab0ca030}$windows.data.settings.multitasking.windows\windows.data.settings.multitasking.windows]

""=dword:00000001

"EnableFlyout"=dword:00000001

"url7"="P:\\Apps & Cracks\\Windows\\_Code\\AutoHotKey\\Tests\\Advanced Window .ahk"

"url15"="P:\\Apps & Cracks\\Windows\\_Code\\AutoHotKey\\Advanced Window "

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\Backup\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy!Global.]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\Backup\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_cw5n1h2txyewy!Global.]

"Url"="wpnidm:http://cdn.flipboard.com/smileandtravel.com/2d83370fc98da7c39bc3cee1271e91a5adae/thumbnail.jpg"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Nurgo-Software\Aqua]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Nurgo-Software\Aqua\WindowResizer]

"To"=dword:00000001

"ToOuterEdges"=dword:00000001

"ToInnerEdges"=dword:00000001

"ToAdjacentCorners"=dword:00000001

"IgnoreFastMovements"=dword:00000001

"MaxVelocity"=dword:0007a120

"Window/Tools/Isped"="True"

"Window/Tools/pedToName"="AppWorkspace"

"Window/History/Isped"="True"

"Window/History/pedToName"="AppWorkspace"

"Window/Layers/Isped"="True"

"Window/Layers/pedToName"="AppWorkspace"

"Window/Colors/Isped"="True"

"Window/Colors/pedToName"="AppWorkspace"

"ToClipEdges"=dword:00000001

"ToPlayhead"=dword:00000001

"ToAnimationEdges"=dword:00000001

"ToMarkers"=dword:00000001

"ToQuestionSets"=dword:00000001

"Canvasping"=dword:00000001

"Playheadping"=dword:00000000

"CanvaspingEnabled"=dword:00000000

"DisableTaskshots"="False"

"TaskbarshotSize"="10"

"EnableTo"="True"

"NoOfshotExclusion"="7"

"shotName1"="wmplayer.exe"

"shotExec1"="True"

"shotIcon1"=""

"shotExct1"="False"

"shotName2"="tbrush.exe"

"shotExec2"="True"

"shotIcon2"=""

"shotExct2"="False"

"shotName3"="powerpnt.exe"

"shotExec3"="True"

"shotIcon3"=""

"shotExct3"="False"

"shotName"="qemu.exe"

"shotExec"="True"

"shotIcon"=""

"shotExct"="False"

"shotName5"="mplayer2.exe"

"shotExec5"="True"

"shotIcon5"=""

"shotExct5"="False"

"shotName"="GanttProject"

"shotExec"="False"

"shotIcon"=""

"shotExct"="False"

"shotName7"="lightroom.exe"

"shotExec7"="True"

"shotIcon7"="S"

"shotExct7"="False"

"ToGrid"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.BackgroundTasks\PackageId\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_1000.223.1000.0_x__cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\Global..AppX58dwf1xwjzeer05zcpfeag883wvc9y0.wwa]

"DisplayName"="Global."

"Description"="Global."

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.BackgroundTasks\PackageId\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_1000.223.1000.0_x__cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\Global..AppX58dwf1xwjzeer05zcpfeag883wvc9y0.wwa\CustomProperties]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.BackgroundTasks\PackageId\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_1000.223.1000.0_x__cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\Global..AppXtq1qr7x809h0sw08qzdq0nerjx.mca]

"DisplayName"="Global."

"Description"="Global."

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.BackgroundTasks\PackageId\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_1000.223.1000.0_x__cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\Global..AppXtq1qr7x809h0sw08qzdq0nerjx.mca\CustomProperties]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_1000.223.1000.0_x__cw5n1h2txyewy\ActivatableClassId\Global..wwa]

"DisplayName"="Global."

"Description"="Global."

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SettingsGroupMultiTasking/Description}"=" settings"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SettingsGroupMultiTasking/HighKeywords}"="multitasking settings; windows; a window;arrange windows"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SettingsPageMultiTasking-2/HighKeywords}"=" settings;timeline settings;virtual desktop settings;sets settings;organise desktop;ping;organize desktop"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SettingsPageMultiTasking/HighKeywords}"=" settings;timeline settings;virtual desktop settings;sets settings"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SystemSettings_MultiTasking_AeroEnabled/Description}"="Automatically  windows to the sides or corners of the "

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SystemSettings_MultiTasking_AeroEnabled/HighKeywords}"="window ;aero ; settings;multitasking settings"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SystemSettings_MultiTasking_JointResizeEnabled/Description}"="When I resize a ped window, resize any adjacent ped window"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SystemSettings_MultiTasking_JointResizeEnabled/HighKeywords}"="divider; resize; settings;multitasking settings;resize ped window"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SystemSettings_MultiTasking_Enabled/Description}"="When I  a window, show what I can  next to it"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SystemSettings_MultiTasking_Enabled/HighKeywords}"="suggest windows;; ;choose window; settings;multitasking settings"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SystemSettings_MultiTasking_FillEnabled/Description}"="Automatically resize ped windows to fill the  space"

"@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SystemSettings_MultiTasking_FillEnabled/HighKeywords}"="window fill;resize windows;adjust windows; windows; fill;auto ; settings;multitasking settings"

"@%ProgramFiles%\\Hyper-V\\InAbout.dll,-132"="Hyper-V Manager provides management access to your virtualization platform."

"@%systemroot%\\system32\\pmc.dll,-710"="Manages local printers and remote print servers."

"@%ProgramFiles%\\Hyper-V\\InAbout.dll,-501"="Hyper-V Quick Create enables rapid creation of virtual machines from a gallery of curated virtual machine images."

"NewTabPageFlightId"="msnallexpusers,muidflt10cf,muidflt1cf,muidflt28cf,muidflt8cf,muidflt9cf,muidflt300cf,pnehp1cf,moneyhp1cf,bingcollabhp2cf,starthz1cf,audexhz1cf,compliancehz1cf,gallery5cf,mp1cf,jslltelemetry,mpcf,1s-bing-news,vebudumu0302020,bbh20200521msn"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Repository\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_1000.223.1000.0_x__cw5n1h2txyewy\Applications\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_cw5n1h2txyewy!Global.]

"DisplayName"="Global."

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\Splash\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy!Global.]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_cw5n1h2txyewy\Splash\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_cw5n1h2txyewy!Global.]
```